# Virtual Box Guest can't access the internet when host uses WIFI but can when host uses 100baseT

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, debian

I have a window 7 VB host, with wired and wifi.  Normally, it is connected to my home net via a wire.

I have a a Debian guest with two adapters configured: one id bridged, and one is host only.

When plugged in, my VM hits the internet without a second thought, but when windows is connected via wifi, the VM can no longer reach the internet.

I thought that VBox would be using the host as its internet gateway, so I don't see why connecting to the internet via the host should fail when the host is connected via wifi.

How do I configure Virtual box networking so that my VM can reach the net regardless of network medium?

Comment: Does VBox has special settings for bridged adapter? I mean, your host has two, and VBox uses LAN always. I believe, you may manually force it to use WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

I was even dumber then I thought.  Once I added a Wifi nic to the host under virtual box, and brought the wifi adapter up under the guest, it worked. Sigh.

Comment: What did you do? VirtualBox has no concept of WiFi inside.

Comment: I thought that having a bridged network interface would be all that I needed, but I was incorrect. In order to use the wifi nic on the laptop, I had to define it to virtual box and enable it on the guest.

Comment: What you *should* have done: tell VBox to bridge the virtual adapter to your WiFi adapter.

Comment: I thought I had, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not a routing but rather wireless security issue. Something along the lines of wpa_supplicant only supporting one adapter(virtual or physical) at a time. Try disabling WIFI encryption (just for the test) and see it the guest would be able to connect while the host is connected via unencrypted WIFI.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you, I expect the windows host to be the internet gateway, and the VM to communicate via a "wired" connection to and through the windows host.

Comment: For the host to be the gateway - the guest network adapter type should be "NAT" instead of "bridged"

Comment: Because bridged makes it possible for the guest to use/share the hosts NICs as if they belonged to the guest?     But can I assign the guest's IP (so I can hit the web services on the guest without adjusting the host file every time) ?